# how to auto update SQl database with google sheets data

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

I have a google sheet that has data on it. I have a MySQL database that will be an exact copy of the Google Sheets data. I want to make it so when they save the page it will auto update a MySQL database with the new data that the website will pull data from. Here is my script so far. I can connect to the database but can't see how to update it with the sheets data automatically.

```js
var server = 'server ip';
var dbName = 'db name';
var username = 'user';
var password = 'pass';
var port = '3306';

function CreateConnection() {
  var url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);

  conn.close();
}
```

Here are my columns:

1. ID  (auto increments)
2. CUs No
3. Name
4. Phone
5. License No.
6. Status 1-5
7. Last Update

Comment: That's not PHP. Is this JavaScript? (With JDBC??)

Comment: This is google-apps-script, i.e. another doppelgänger of javascript that sits in Google apps like sheets, docs etc

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you have a Sheet loaded with columns and values, and you want to insert them into an existing MySQL database. I see that you already scripted the [connection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-connection) to the database, so you are very close to reaching your goal.

First of all you would need to subtract the data from the Sheets. To manage that you could use [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and save the information in one variable. Now the target is to create a SQL statement that inserts the desired values into the table. It may look similar to this one:

```sql
INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7) VALUES ('column1Value', 'column2Value', 'column3Value', 'column4Value', 'column5Value', 'column6Value', 'column7Value');
```

Keeping that structure on mind you can easily build your own statement by substituting the placeholders and updating the values to include the array of previously saved data. Then, you would only need to send that statement to the database. To do so you could use [`JdbcConnection.createStatement()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-connection#createstatement) and [`JdbcStatement.execute()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-statement#executesql). Please, ask me any additional doubts to better document this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically updating db based on entire sheet might not be a good idea, because of manual errors while filling the sheet. So instead I would suggest go with a form based approach where on form submit you have a trigger that runs a function to insert that new entry into the database. Benefit of using form is that prevents human error. And if not that way then you could keep a flag column and based on its value you can run the ones that haven't been already processed into db using a time based trigger which runs say every 10 mins. All this is important to prevent duplicate entries in the db, and to avoid manual errors.